# when and why to use display inline-block

Tags: html, css

I am very confused about using inline-block for example:

html...

```
<div id="main">
  <div class="one">inline-block</div>
  <div class="two">inline-block</div>
</div>
```

Sometimes `inline-block` works when I use for `#main` and sometimes it works when I use to `.one` , `.two` and also sometimes it doesn't work when I use for `#main` and sometimes it doesn't work when I use to `.one` , `.two`

Can anyone describe about inline-block properly when and why?

**Edit**

I mean setting `display: inline-block;` to `#main` also get inline-block to `.one` and `.two` elements without setting `display: inline-block;` to `.one` and `.two`, but I couldn't know why?

Comment: What about the CSS you're using here? Because I think that maybe you have a wrong concept of how CSS cascade really works.

Comment: It looks like you would like to have `div.one` and `div.two` side-by-side? If so, restate your question accordingly.

Comment: See this [example](http://jsfiddle.net/DLkKb/1/).

Answer (score 4):

**Inline-Block Demo**

I set up a Fiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/audetwebdesign/NxMLu/ to illustrate four scenarios:

Consider the following code:

```
<div class="main">
  <div class="inner one">inline-block</div>
  <div class="inner two">inline-block</div>
</div>
```

and the following CSS:

```
.main {
    outline: 2px dotted blue;
    padding: 5px;
}
.one, .two {
    outline: 1px dotted blue;
}
.ex2 .inner {
    display: inline-block;
}
.ex3.main {
    display: inline-block;
}
.ex4.main, .ex4 .inner {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

**Example 1: all blocks**

By default, the `<div>` elements display as blocks and their width's stretch to fill the width of the screen.

**Example 2: children are inline-blocks**

In this case, the child `<div>` elements are displayed as `inline-block` and as a result their widths shrink-to-fit and they appear side by side within the full width parent element.

**Example 3: parent is an inline-block**

In this case, the parent element's width is shrink-to-fit the content, and the children's with are also shrink-to-fit BUT each child is on a separate line because they are still block level elements.

**Example 4: parent and child elements are inline-blocks**

Similar to example 3 AND the child elements appear side-by-side because they are now in an inline-flow context.

**When To Use Inline-Block**

The `inline-block` display type is useful when you need to apply top and bottom margins or padding to elements that need to appear on a single line, for example, a horizontal navigation bar.  The main advantage of `inline-block` elements is that they will respond to the `text-align: center` declaration, so you can center all the elements in a line and have some control over margins and padding.